# Load KML marks on map using Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, kml

I'm working on a iOS project with Swift on Xcode, and i need to show a map with some routes drawn on it. I created the map view using Google Maps SDK for iOS and it works well. I use KML.swift to parse the KML file.

The problem is that i want to load the routes for the map from a KML and i don't see how to do it. On Android, the SDK allows you to add a layer from a KML and add that layer to the map easy (more or less), but i can't find the way to do something like that on the iOS SDK.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading this document?(https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut)

Comment: @d.datul1990 Thanks, but i read that documentation searching some information about iOS support and i don't find something related. This documentation is only KML basic information and come references for javascript and android sdk, but i guess nothing on iOS sdk.

Comment: Sorry for that. KML rendering is currently only available in Javascript API, not in iOS SDK yet. I'm currently reading this docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can now do so with GoogleMapsUtils. The KML file can be parsed using `GMUKMLParser` and rendered with `GMSMapView`.

Create instances of GMSMapView and GMUKMLParser

```
let mapView: GMSMapView!
let kmlParser: GMUKMLParser!

func renderKml() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "uae_map", ofType: "kml") else {
        print("Invalid path")
        return
    }
    
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    
    kmlParser = GMUKMLParser(url: url)
    kmlParser.parse()
    
    let renderer = GMUGeometryRenderer(
        map: mapView,
        geometries: kmlParser.placemarks,
        styles: kmlParser.styles,
        styleMaps: kmlParser.styleMaps
    )
    
    renderer.render()
}
```